# Add additional images of product via magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, product, csv, product-images, magmi

i am using magento 1.9, i add images in the product sheet by magmi through urls of external site. they works fine, but i want to upload more products photo in the product that have more than 10 photos. so there is no media_gallery row in product csv file. I learn the techniques of magmi product import but doesn't know the meaning of: sku,media_gallery
00001,/image1.jpg;/image2.jpg. how to use it. So please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for the media_gallery CSV field is:

a) start each gallery image with `+` or `-` (`+` means include in gallery, `-` means exclude from gallery)

b) write the image filename first followed by the image label separated by `::` eg `/myImage.jpg::label for myImage`

c) separate each gallery image with `;`

So for one image:

```
sku, media_gallery
00001, +/myImage.jpg::label for my image;
```

And for two images

```
sku, media_gallery
00001, +/myImage.jpg::label for my image;+/myImage2.jpg::label for my image2;
```

And so on. I think you can replace the image file name with your external URL to the images but I have not tried that.

*Additonal Edit following new questions below*

a) Put the CSV file in the CSV folder which is normally var/import/

b) Regarding the errors, please double check your domains. This domain `http://textileexport.in/admintextileexport/files/thIMG-20150317-WA0009_gyt9shk1.jpg` returns 404.

c) If the other domains are correct, try adding a `/` after the `+` sign because I am not sure if you need that or not. So try:

```
sku, media_gallery
00001, +/http://example.com/myImage.jpg::label for my image;+/http://example.com/myImage2.jpg::label for my image2;
```

If you are still having problems please put here a few lines from your CSV file so we can review its syntax.

Comment: Thanks but let me know where to put it. Filesystem Path to magento directory: or in CSVs base directory.

Comment: There is also an error occur while running magmi with profile: